# How to evaluate model accuracy at tail of empirical distribution?

Tags: predictive-modeling, cross-validation, model-evaluations

I am making a nonlinear regression on stationary dependent variable and I want to precisely forecast extreme values of this variable. So when my model predicts extreme values I want them to be highly accurate. Less extreme forecasts (eg. positioned near mean) don't need to be "as much" accurate.

What are some useful metrics with favorable statistical properties, used to compare multiple models when tail accuracy matters?

Comment: Tail of what distribution?

Comment: Of dependent stationary variable which I try to model.

Comment: What kind of nonlinear regression are you doing? Regression, by design, tends to predict means.

Comment: Regression algorithm doesn't matter. I want to make accurate forecasts (conditional means) of extreme values of my dependent variable. When my dependent variable is close to its distributional mean (stationarity condition) i don't need high accuracy.